# Confusion while Hard Surface modeling the Spaceship

Tags: modeling, mesh, uv, topology

I just want to know, What is the ideal approach to model marked area of spaceship based on the respective Model sheet. When I model it as single object it requires a lot of time for Topology.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This artist has used many techniques.

You have done a good job seeing the segments.

A combination of the suggested techniques may work for you.  Here are some ways you could model segments like this in Blender.

**A. Checker select, inset, simple deform with a "twist"**

Create a cylinder with quite a few subdivisions
Select the edge loops and press F3 to search for checker select, and then inset some of the loops with the I quick key.  Size them down.

[image]

Then, apply the twist modifier.

[image]

**B.Array, Curve modifier, and Boolean**

create some square curves with rounded sides and lay them out so they are one row of your pattern.

[image]

Add a solidifier modifier to these

[image]

Add a bezier circle and a cylinder with exactly the same origin points. The bezier circle will be the guide.

Add an array with "fit curve" selected, choosing the bezier circle as the curve. Choose either relative or constant offset and position everything according to the design.
You need a curve modifier as well, with the bezier circle as object.

[image]

You can boolean quite a bit of detail into the engine at this point.  You may have to do more than one boolean to get something you are pleased with and combine it with the other segments you have created.

[image]

Of course, there are more techniques involved in the other sections to research.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. These tips gonna help me to do much more faster

Answer (score 1):

The real thing seems to have been constructed from separate parts, so I suggest you follow this approach in your model...

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would model the elements separate. There are a number of ways you can approach. One way would be to use spin.

Select your object, go into edit mode.

change your view to above the object.

select the vertices and move them off center of the origin. Spin will use origin as the pivot point.
[image]

with the vertices selected press alt E, and choose spin.

[image]

you can adjust with the menu at lower left part of screen. You might also look into arrays being controlled by empties. Good luck!